# notification firing 6 times a minute (swift4)

Tags: ios, date, notifications, swift4, picker

Every time my notification timer goes off it repeats 6 times via in the minute. I only want the notification to fire once per minute. How can I write the code so the notification only goes off once per minute.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()
    var passingDate : Date?
    @IBOutlet var dptext: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        createDatePicker()
        timer  = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.testDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func createDatePicker() {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        dptext.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        dptext.inputView = datePicker
    }

    @objc func testDate() {
        if Calendar.current.isDate(datePicker.date, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .minute) {
            print("success")
            if let passingDate = passingDate, Calendar.current.isDate(datePicker.date, equalTo: passingDate, toGranularity: .minute) {
                // Previous date existing, and is in the same minute as the current date : do nothing
                return
            }
            passingDate = datePicker.date
            print("success")
        }
    }

    @objc func donePressed() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        dptext.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: `timeInterval: 10` means it fires every 10 seconds. It did exactly what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `timeInterval` from `10` to `60` :

```
timer  = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.testDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```